# Extracting duplicates from two databases for presentation

Tags: excel, sqlite

I've been spinning in circles trying to work this out....

I Have an SQLite d'base with multiple tables, and about 125k records, relating recovered files.

I've been asked to compare duplicates across  2 groups of files - ACCESSIBLE and INACCESSIBLE

I'm able to extract the categories like so...

```
ACCESSIBLE
SELECT fileoffset, fileName, folderName, hash, myDescription, myUnique, category
FROM c4p_index 
WHERE (category = 1 OR category = 2 OR category = 3 OR category = 4 OR category = 5)
AND myUnique=1
AND (fileoffset = 0 
AND folderName NOT LIKE '%\Lost Files\%' 
AND folderName NOT LIKE '%Unallocated Clusters%' 
AND fileName NOT LIKE '%Unallocated Clusters%' 
AND folderName NOT LIKE '%thumbs.db%' 
AND fileName NOT LIKE '%thumbs.db%' 
AND folderName NOT LIKE '%thumbcache%' 
AND fileName NOT LIKE '%thumbcache% 
AND myDescription NOT LIKE %deleted%' 
AND myDescription NOT LIKE '%recycled%')

INACCESSIBLE
SELECT fileoffset, fileName, folderName, hash, myDescription, myUnique, category
FROM c4p_index 
WHERE (category = 1 OR category = 2 OR category = 3 OR category = 4 OR category = 5)
AND myUnique=1
AND (fileoffset > 0 
OR folderName LIKE '%\Lost Files\%' 
OR folderName LIKE '%Unallocated Clusters%' 
OR fileName LIKE '%Unallocated Clusters%' 
OR folderName LIKE '%thumbs.db%' 
OR fileName LIKE '%thumbs.db%' 
OR folderName LIKE '%thumbcache%' 
OR fileName LIKE '%thumbcache% 
OR myDescription LIKE %deleted%' 
OR myDescription LIKE '%recycled%')
```

My problem is that Having identified the unique values within each GROUP using
'myUnique=1'
I now need to compare the values in the HASH column BETWEEN the two separate outputs, I've managed to do it the long winded way by exporting it to EXCEL as a .CSV and manipulating the data.

But I'm certain I could probably do it using SQLite all the way....??

My thoughts are that if the outputs can be exported into a new D'base and then the final count of duplicates between the groups be exported into a Spreadsheet for presentation.

can any one help out?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to do. Do you have any sample input/output where the input is the results from the two separate select statements and the output your comparison? And a description of the manipulation you did on excel could help describe what you're trying to do too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ATTACH](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_attach.html) to open multiple database files:

```
ATTACH 'C:\some\where\accessible.db' AS accessible;
ATTACH 'C:\some\where\inaccessible.db' AS inaccessible;
```

Then you can copy data from those databases:

```
CREATE TABLE hash_A AS
SELECT hash FROM accessible.c4p_index WHERE ...;
CREATE TABLE hash_I AS
SELECT hash FROM inaccessible.c4p_index WHERE ...;
```

Then you can compare it in whatever way you like:

```
SELECT hash FROM hash_I EXCEPT SELECT hash FROM hash_A;
```